# Is it Safe to DELETE SharePoint AppFabric Logs (.ETL)?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, logs, app-fabric, fabric

My SharePoint WFE contains AppFabric Logs (.ETL) files

Location: C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log\Traces
e.g. File name: "lease_traces_131189918650268910_000051.ETL"

These logs are from 2 years back till today. Each having size 150MB. This is consuming much size. Can I delete them?

Comment: I have found this article on how to prevent growth of these logs but have yet to find an answer on how if one should delete these, did you find anything out on this?

Comment: https://flinchbot.com/2014/02/28/the-hidden-logs-that-could-crash-your-lync-servers/